# How to read an excel dataframe from a private GitHub repository using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, github

I have a working website made using django. I have a private GitHub repository, within it I have excel files which I want to read using `pandas read_excel` and use on the website. The reason I have made the repository private is because the data is company specific.

1) How do I read an excel file using pandas from a private GitHub repository? Do I need to set up personal access token?

2) After a user logs in to my website, is there then a way to require a further password when they navigate to try and view their company specific dataframe? For example, "User A" will only have access to "Dataframe A", and "User B" will only have access to "Data frame B".

On my local system, the following code works to be able to read the dataframe:

```
file_path = 'C:/Users/james/Desktop/projects/path/to/excel/file
df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
```

For my live website, my code which produces the problem is:

```
URL_path = 'https://github.com/path/to/excel/file/in/private/repository
df = pd.read_excel(URL_path)
```

I am able to read the excel files on my local computer, but when I try to read in from my private github, I get the following error, even though I know I am using the correct url:

`urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found`

I verified this by signing out of my github account, and trying to access the github url with my excel in it, it takes me to a `404 not found` page since I am not logged in. When I login to my github account, the same URL takes me to the correct page.

Answer (score 0):

You should need to use a PAO (person access token) from github if the repo is set to private.

You would then need to gather the raw url link to the data and make sure to decode it properly prior to using pandas to read it.

Check out this tutorial here; it's using a csv but the idea is essentially the same:

https://medium.com/towards-entrepreneurship/importing-a-csv-file-from-github-in-a-jupyter-notebook-e2c28e7e74a5

Comment: thanks for this. Can you explain with a code snippet please? I tried the code in your medium link for an excel file in a private repo but I get an error message - 'TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not bytes'

Comment: my first guess is that you the code incorrectly tells you to use stringIO or some type of buffer that may not be needed. I would look at the specific error and find a reason that that is not working, common with bringing in a csv etc.